# Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, curl, debian

```
<?php
$filename = "xx.gif";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$data = fread($handle, filesize($filename));

// $data is file data
$pvars   = array('image' => base64_encode($data), 'key' => IMGUR_API_KEY);
$timeout = 30;
$curl    = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.xml');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pvars);

$xml = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close ($curl);

var_dump($xml);
?>
```

I'm playing with the Imgur API, but it doesn't seems to work. PHP.net says that `curl_init()` is in PHP5, but my host says it isn't. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

curl is an extension that needs to be installed, it's got nothing to do with the PHP version.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.setup.php

Comment: +1 And if you can't install the curl extension, you can try using shell_exec (or similar) with the curl command. Or you can probably "fake it" with fsockopen.

Comment: That page doesn't say a word about HOW TO install the extension. Any better resources?

Comment: Once you've installed the curl package, have a look in the php.ini file (within /etc). Search for curl. In mine (OpenBSD), I had to remove the comment on the line that said *extension=curl*

Answer (score 131):

On old versions of Debian and Ubuntu, you solved this by installing the Curl extension for PHP, and restarting the webserver. Assuming the webserver is Apache 2:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

On newer versions, the package name as changed:

```
sudo apt install php-curl
```

It's possible you'll need to install more:

```
sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev;
```

Comment: I had to install more in ubuntu:
"sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl;
You'll know if it works because phpinfo() will get a new section with Curl info."

Comment: I expect that `sudo service apache2 restart` should work just as well?

Comment: It's logical to assume that restart = stop + start, but with years of experience with Apache, it hasn't always in the case. I learned to use  an explicit stop and then start to be safe. Sorry, I can't remember the specific potential problems, but you are welcome to use `restart` and see if it works for you.

Comment: did the trick for me also with just  sudo apt-get install php5-curl .. thanks!

Comment: `sudo service apache2 restart` merely restarts Apache.  It is necessary to run this [following the CURL install] in order for Aache/PHP to pick up the added CURL packages, so they will work when the CURL infused PHP script is next run. 

But, I also found that I needed to include `php5-curl` to get satisfaction ;)

Comment: php5-curl Unable to locate packages  after installing `curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev`. what i am missing ?

Comment: @captainchhala Time has marched on since I answered this question 6 years ago. Are you sure you still need to installing PHP 5 and not PHP 7?

Comment: @MarkStosberg i have solved the probelm with `sudo apt install php-curl` and by the way i didn't look at the timestamp :).

Answer (score 14):

Don't have enough reputation to comment yet. Using Ubuntu and a simple:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

**Did NOT work for me.**

For some reason `curl.so` was installed in a location not picked up by default. I checked the `extension_dir` in my php.ini and copied over the `curl.so` to my `extension_dir`

```
cp /usr/lib/php5/20090626/curl.so  /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626
```

Hope this helps someone, adjust your path locations accordingly.

Answer (score 13):

**For Ubuntu**

Install Curl extension for PHP & restart apache server.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**For Windows**

Problem arises because of not including the lib_curl.dll to PHP. 
   also load following extension if not working,so those extension in `php.ini` or remove comment if already exist in `php.ini` file then remove comment.

```
extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_dba.dll
```

Now restart apache server.
If you get an error "Unable to Load php_curl.dll", 
copy SSLEAY32.PHP, libEAY32.dll (OpenSSL) Libraries to the System32 folder.

Comment: The question was tagged as being about Ubuntu and Debian Linux. Your answer does not apply to those environments.

Comment: @MarkStosberg Agreed. Updated answer.

Comment: Not working at all. I do not know whats wrong in this command, but not working. I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Yes worked! This should be the accepted answer! At least for linux anyways.

Answer (score 5):

for php 7.0 on ubuntu use

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl
```

And finally,

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

or

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: find your version: $php --version  version =7.X
then install: $ sudo apt-get install php7.X-curl

Answer (score 4):

do this

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

and restart server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thanks man.. was working in a competetion and I am not comfortable php, curl. Your answer helped me overcome a problem, that took me half a day.

Answer (score 3):

Experienced this on ubuntu 16.04 running PHP 7.1.14. To resolve,first put this in a script and execute. It will return true if curl is installed and enabled,otherwise, it will return false.

```
<?php
    var_dump(extension_loaded('curl'));
?>
```

If it returns false, run

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl
```

And finally,

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

After the restart, the script will return true and hopefully, your error should be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

There is solution with all necessary details for Windows 7 x64:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7qNTi1sEfE8

It is in French, but you can understand everything! I solved same problem, even don't speak French. :-)

Many answers forget to mention that you need to add new version of php_curl.dll file from this location: http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/

I added new version of php_curl.dll from archive php_curl-5.4.3-VC9-x64.zip to folders: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\ext and C:\Windows\System32 and everything was fine!

Answer (score 0):

For **Windows** this worked for me. Go to `php.ini` file and remove the comment from the following lines

```
extension=bz2
extension=curl
```

Just remove the `;` before each line to uncomment. Restart the server and this error will go away

Answer (score -2):

### This is from the official website. php.net

After installation of PHP.

### Windows

Move to Windows\system32 folder:
libssh2.dll, php_curl.dll, ssleay32.dll, libeay32.dll

### Linux

Move to Apache24\bin folder
libssh2.dll

Then uncomment extension=php_curl.dll in php.ini

Answer (score -3):

```
$ch = curl_init('http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.xml'); //initialising our url

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);  //used for https headers 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);  //used for https headers

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode($pvars));  
//the value we post

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //waiting for reponse, default value in php is zero ie, curls normally do not wait for a response

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.5) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/1.0'); 

$output = curl_exec($ch); //the real execution 
curl_close($ch);

echo $output;
```

Try this code. I am not sure about it. But i used it to send xml data to a remote url.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.