"Call to undefined function curl_init()" with php8.2-fpm, nginx, ubuntu
I have an error with curl extension in php, I tried some tutorials from Stackoverflow and others, but I didn't find a solution
My error displayed:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in /some/file.php:27 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /some/file.php on line 27


I try sudo apt-get install php-curl from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6382581/13937777 and doesn't any change
I try to uncomment 'curl' from php.ini file, and doesn't any change
I try sudo apt install php-curl follow by sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev; in https://stackoverflow.com/a/8199206/13937777 and error occur when install libcurl3. So I try sudo apt install libcurl4 from https://askubuntu.com/a/1364067/1772498 after and in doesn't work


Does this answer your question? PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()

@MarkusZeller in small part but not totally, that's why I create this question + answer

One of the answers is just to enable/install the module. That you have to restart the webserver after changing is config (installing or en/disabling mods does) is well known.

Finally I ask chatGPT and it resolve my problem:

sudo apt update
sudo apt install php8.2-curl
sudo systemctl restart php8.2-fpm
sudo systemctl restart nginx

And it's works! Error disappear
